# php directoryIterator - path based on season?

Tags: php, iterator, directory

hey guys,
this works fine:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(get_template_directory().'/images/headers/');
```

however I don't have just /headers but i have a /headers/summer and headers/winter directory that I wanna use as path depending on the current season.

```
$summer = array(3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$path = null;

if ( in_array(date('n'), $summer) ) {
    $path = get_template_directory().'/images/headers/summer/';
} else {
    $path = get_template_directory().'/images/headers/winter/';
}

$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
```

What is wrong with this? My page is blank if I use this!

Comment: `get_template_directory()`is a wordpress specific function, shouldn't matter for the code - just returns the absolute path to the dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 3 possibilits..

1. the $path does not exists, check
   with `if(!is_dir($path)) die('no dir
   there');`
2. your function get_template_directory
   throws a fatal
3. you are using PHP4 where the class
   DirectoryIterator does not exists

Answer (score 1):

I think this should should work fine, I do wonder why you get a white screen. This usually occurs when you receive an fatal error and your error_reporting isn't set correctly.

Please set your error_reporting to E_ALL:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

This should display any error that occur.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have error reporting enabled. Do `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in you script or look up the error in the apache logs.

You may get an error later on the page, because you assume different things about the contents (empty directory maybe?) or wrong rights on the directory (from http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php):

```
Throws an UnexpectedValueException if the path cannot be opened.
```

But without details about the error, this is only guessing.